# Minishift start using hyper-v on windows 10 fails with E1011

Tags: openshift, redhat-containers, minishift

Windows 10 Version 1607 
minishift v1.3.1+a2d3799
CDK v3.1.1-1
Vagrant 2.0.0

When I try to start minishift I'm getting an error pretty early on: 
PS C:\minishift> minishift start
Starting local OpenShift cluster using 'hyperv' hypervisor...
E1011 16:57:09.569574   13196 start.go:282] Error starting the VM: Error starting stopped host: exit status 1. Retrying
E1011 16:57:12.173524   13196 start.go:282] Error starting the VM: Error starting stopped host: exit status 1. Retrying
E1011 16:57:14.765997   13196 start.go:282] Error starting the VM: Error starting stopped host: exit status 1. Retrying
Error starting the VM: Error starting stopped host: exit status 1
Error starting stopped host: exit status 1
Error starting stopped host: exit status 1

Any thoughts on what to look into would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Are you also using VirtualBox on the same host. I believe you can't use HypverV and VirtualBox on Windows unless something has changed.

Comment: Hi Graham.  No, I'm trying to make due without it.

Comment: For the OP, adding `--show-libmachine-logs -v 5`e.g. `minishift start --show-libmachine-logs -v 5` can help to show a decent amount of debug as to whats going on