# Can RH development tools be run in Windows 10 Bash shell, i.e. WSL?

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm having issues trying to run minishift in a cmd shell.  I'd prefer to run it under Bash using WSL but haven't found any advice to help set that up.  Is it possible/recommended?

Thanks,
Robin

Comment: Can you describe the actual problem/error you are having with running it in a cmd shell? Are you trying to use VirtualBox or HyperV? Are you already running other VMs with HyperV?

Comment: I posted this question to cover the cmd shell issue, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48139682/minishift-start-using-hyperv-fails-when-devtools-installed-on-a-different-drive.  However, on moving .minishift to the same drive as the dev tools, and adding a MINISHIFT_HOME to point at it, I'm now getting a different error: 

D:\DevelopmentSuite>minishift start
...-- Starting Minishift VM .... FAIL E0107 17:36:41.497791   16800 start.go:356] Error starting the VM: Error starting stopped host: exit status 1. Retrying.
Error starting the VM: Error starting stopped host: exit status 1

Comment: ...using HyperV

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton I see you posted to a question related to my problem, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46698396/minishift-start-using-hyper-v-on-windows-10-fails-with-e1011.  I do have vbox installed on this machine.  I haven't had issues with Docker running with HyperV, but is there a known compatibility issue with minishift and HyperV if vbox is also installed?

Comment: You just can't use VirtualBox and HyperV at the same time as far as I know.